# The name doesnt change but the path does in the array

Tags: php, arrays

So I am having issues understanding how to iterate over an array that looks as such in php:

```
 $styles = array(
   'css' => array(
       'name' => array(
          'core-css', 
          'bootstrap-css',
          'bootstrap-responsive-css'
        ),
       'path' => array(
           get_bloginfo('stylesheet_url'), 
           get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css',
           get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.responsive.min.css'
        ),
    ),
 );
```

Essentially this styles gets passed to a constructor of a class which then iterates over the array in a method that looks like this (note this array is stored class level in a protected value called _options, hence the $this->_options in the following code:

```
foreach ( $this->_options as $key => $value ) {
    // load all the css files
    if (isset ( $this->_options ['css'] )) {
        foreach ( $value ['name'] as $name ) {
            foreach ( $value ['path'] as $path ) {
                wp_enqueue_style ( $name, $path );
            }

        }
     }
}
```

This will spit out something like:

- core-css style.css
- core-css bootstrap
- core-css bootstrap-responsive

.

The problem should be clear right now, **the name never changes** and I think it has **something to do with how I am iterating over the array of, essentially, arrays**.

So your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `path` array is not apart of the `name` array, and should look something like:

```
foreach ( $this->_options as $key => $value ) {
    // load all the css files
    if (isset ( $this->_options ['css'] )) {
        foreach ( $value ['path'] as $k=>$path ) {
            wp_enqueue_style ( $value['name'][$k], $path );
        }
     }
}
```

Or, you could always change the structure of your array:

```
$styles = array(
    'css' => array(
        array(
            'name'=>'core-css',
            'path'=>get_bloginfo('stylesheet_url')
        ),
        array(
            'name'=>'bootstrap-css',
            'path'=>get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'
        ),
        array(
            'name'=>'bootstrap-responsive-css',
            'path'=>get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.responsive.min.css'
        )
    )
);

foreach($this->_options as $key => $value){
    if (isset ( $this->_options ['css'] )) {
        foreach($this->_options ['css'] as $k=>$v){
             wp_enqueue_style ( $v['name'], $v['path'] );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I plan to do nothing with the $name in the first foreach loop so is there a better way to handle this or is this way the cleanest?

Comment: i see nothing wrong with servering up the `name` array by a numeric key, so long as the keys will match up

Comment: The other problem with this, as opposed to whats in the OP is that now the last name is used but the first css sheet is used. where a before the first name was used but the sheet would change.... is that something on how I am walking through the data? Essentially the sheet never changes.

Comment: I posted an alternative, if you want to give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

Hope that order matches, other way you in trouble.
Something like this:

```
if (isset($this->_options['css'])) {
    foreach ($this->_options['css']['name'] as $key => $name) {
        echo $name; // Your name
        echo $this->_options['css']['path'][$key]; // Your math
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to create the array such that the name matches or it validates before hand or no?

Comment: Not sure if I understan question. Did you mean something like this `array('css'=>array('core-css' => 'stylesheet_url', ..))` ?